# LWJGL with Slick-Util use a lot of RAM to load texture

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, ram, slick2d

If I use the Slick-Util to load textures into LWJGL it uses a lot of RAM. Here an example with the console-output:

```
Message.info ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1000000 + "MB");
TextureManager.loadTexture("gui.wallpaper", "resources/wallpaper.jpg");
Message.info ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1000000 + "MB");
```

The "TextureManager.loadTexture(...)" method is the following:

```
String textureFileFormat;
if (thePath.contains("png")) {
    textureFileFormat = "PNG";
} else if (thePath.contains("jpg")) {
    textureFileFormat = "JPG";
} else if (thePath.contains("jpeg")) {
    textureFileFormat = "JPG";
} else {
    textureFileFormat = "PNG";
}

theTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture(textureFileFormat, new FileInputStream(thePath), true);

// === Store it onto the HashTable === //
textures.put(theName, theTexture);
```

This uses (like viewable in the console output) quit 80 MB. Why? The "wallpaper.jpg" is just 290KB lage!

What is wrong?

This is the console output:

```
2013-09-24 21:32:40 [INFO] [CLIENT] 4MB
Tue Sep 24 21:32:40 CEST 2013 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
2013-09-24 21:32:41 [INFO] [CLIENT] 89MB
```

I hope, that somebody of you know a solution.

Comment: For how long does it use 89MB? There might be some internal processing requiring memory that is freed up at some point after your console output.

Comment: It uses the 89MB until the Game is closed.